# Fechar modal depois que salvar no Banco

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Fala Meus amigos
Tenho o seguinte Modal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que ao apertar em salvar ele feche o modal e atualiza somente a tabela, fiz o seguinte codigo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele esta fechando porem fica td escuro na pagina e para usar tenho que carregar td novamente com o F5:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o Código JS:

```js
$('#salvarPro').click(function() {

            var Ndesc = $("#NDesc").val();
            var Nqtd = $("#NQtd").val();
            var Nvalor = $("#NValor").val();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "salvar.php",
                data: {
                    desc: Ndesc,
                    qtn: Nqtd,
                    valor: Nvalor
                }
            }).done(function(resposta) {
                $('#ModalNovo').hide();
                alert(resposta);
                GerarTabela();
            }).fail(function() {
                $('#ModalNovo').hide();
                alert('falha ao Cadastrar');
                GerarTabela();
            });
        });
```

E o HTML do Modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalNovo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="TituloModalCentralizado">Novo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="disabledTextInput">Desc</label>
                        <input type="text" id="NDesc" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="disabledTextInput">Qtd</label>
                        <input type="text" id="NQtd" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="disabledTextInput">Valor</label>
                        <input type="text" id="NValor" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="button" id="salvarPro" class="btn btn-success">Salvar Produto</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá Consegui resolver de uma forma simples, na hr de salvar eu dei um click virtual no botão cancelar
desse jeito:

```js
 $('#salvarPro').click(function() {

            var Ndesc = $("#NDesc").val();
            var Nqtd = $("#NQtd").val();
            var Nvalor = $("#NValor").val();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "salvar.php",
                data: {
                    desc: Ndesc,
                    qtn: Nqtd,
                    valor: Nvalor
                }
            }).done(function(resposta) {
                $("#FecharModal").trigger('click');
                GerarTabela();
            }).fail(function() {
                $("#FecharModal").trigger('click');
                GerarTabela();
            });
        });
```

vlw a todos

Comment: Que bom q resolver, mas isso é uma gambiarra braba ein ahhaha, da uma olhada na minha resposta, lá mostra uma forma melhor de fazer.

Answer (score 1):

O que eu percebi é que você está usando `$('#ModalNovo').hide()` mas conforme a documentação do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalhide) o evento para fechar o modal é `$('#ModalNovo').modal('hide')` para exibir `$('#ModalNovo').modal('show')`, lá há outros eventos de controle do modal, da uma olhada lá e aconselho a usar conforme orientações deles e não fazendo `.trigger()` que é um paliativo.

Comment: Concordo, se seguir a documentação do bootstrap, é o correto a se fazer

Answer (score 0):

Tente retirar o **alert**, depois me diga se funcionou, pois o alerta é bloqueante e bloqueia tudo que estiver em volta enquanto não clicar em ok, e não sei se o alert está sendo exibido, esse é o problema aparentemente.

Edit: Então talvez o erro seja na sua função `GerarTabela` que faz ter este comportamento porque seu códico até onde mostrou está correto, poste o códico da função que ajuda nós te ajudar :)

Comment: Tirei e não foi

Comment: Olá Samuel já editei :)

Comment: comentei uma solução que eu fiz

Comment: Ok, marque a sua resposta como resolvida pra sinalizar que a sua pergunta foi esclarecida :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando o seguinte código:

```
$("#SuaModal").modal('hide');
```

Um exemplo de implementação:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Receita/Create",
                data: viewModel,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (d) {
                    swal({
                            title: "Sucesso!",
                            text: "Item criado com sucesso.",
                            confirmButtonColor: "#66BB6A",
                            type: "success",
                        });
                        $("#ReceitaModal").modal('hide');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Falha ao Cadastrar!",
                        text: "Código do erro: " + data.status + ", tente novamente.",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
                        type: "error"
                    });
                 //em caso de falha mantenho a modal aberta, mas se quiser pode por aqui tbm o código q falei
                }
            });
```